# Add Number of Empty Cells in a Column Limiting To Last Data Cell

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets, production, project-organization

Looking to add a cell function that counts the number of blank cells in a column, but only to the bottom row of data. Each row in my spreadsheet is a customer order and the sheet keeps track of order assembly progress, each task is grouped into a column and if the cell is blank it means it is yet to be finished.

Tasks include columns F-K, other rows will not be counted

Goal: Number of incomplete(Blank) tasks in a column will be shown as a number at the top of the sheet.

Problem: When using `=COUNTBLANK (x3:x)` The function counts all blank rows to the bottom of the sheet, Need to limit this to the bottom of the data. That number changes depending on how many orders are on the sheet so this number needs to be adaptive to the bottom of the data(Last order)

Link to copy of Sheet: [Order Priority Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kfbHYRaTCfxLjHKohh2ScyrowOVbUw9XIG1PrhpWMYs/edit?usp=sharing)

Any Additional Information, misunderstandings, or questions please ask. I understand if my descriptions were not clear and would be more than happy to help you help me!

Comment: Based on your provided sample, give this a try in F2 and copy over: `=countblank(F3:index(A:A,count(A:A)+2))`

Comment: @pnuts It would for column F, heh, need to absolute the references for column A, good catch.  Updated formula: `=countblank(F3:index(F:F,count($A:$A)+2))` Also realized I was putting the index(*column* argument incorrectly. Geeze,that's what I get for not testing first ><

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=COUNTBLANK($A$3:INDEX($A:$A,LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($A:$A)>0),ROW($A:$A))))
```

adjust the column references for your desired column

This part of the formula:

```
LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($A:$A)>0),ROW($A:$A))
```

returns the last row number in column A that appears blank.

However, if, for example, you wanted to count all of the blanks in the range `F3:Kn` where `n` is the last used row in column A, then try this modification:

```
=COUNTBLANK($F$3:INDEX($F:$K,LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($A:$A)>0),ROW($A:$A)),6))
```

If you just want to count each column separately, again, using column A to determine the last relevant row, then, (for column F):

```
=COUNTBLANK(F$3:INDEX(F:F,LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN($A:$A)>0),ROW($A:$A))))
```

and fill right

Comment: @pnuts I didn't realize he wanted to some all of the blanks in multiple columns.  But to sum the blanks in multiple columns, it's just a matter of adding a column reference to the index formula

Comment: @pnuts After examining his worksheet, I am thinking that the last relevant row, for any column, would be the last filled row in column A

Comment: Thank you so much worked first try without any problems!

Answer (score 0):

Column A seems to be a column where the last populated cell defines the extents of the data. Dates are considered numbers so the row with the last populated date in column A would be,

```
=match(1e99, a:a)
```

To count the blanks in F3:<last cell>,

```
=countblank(f3:index(f:f, match(1e99, $a:$a)))
```